# Spring Batch - how to fail job when called from SpringApplicationBuilder

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

I need to be able to have my program exit with an error code so that the scheduler that initiated the program can know that it failed.  Currently, I am running my job via SpringApplicationBuilder.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBatchProcessing
@Slf4j
public class WeeklyImportApplication extends DefaultBatchConfigurer {

...

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        handleArguments(args);

        new SpringApplicationBuilder(WeeklyImportApplication.class).listeners(new CustomLoggingConfigurationApplicationListener(logConfigurer)).run(args);

        finished();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job weeklyImport(JobBuilderFactory jobs, Step determineTableName, Step determineColumnNames, Step readAccessDb) {
        return jobs.get("weeklyImport").incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer()).flow(determineTableName).next(determineColumnNames).next(readAccessDb).end().build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step determineTableName(StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory, ItemReader<String> tableNameReader, TableNameWriter tableNameWriter) {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("determineTableName").<String, String> chunk(100).reader(tableNameReader).writer(tableNameWriter).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step determineColumnNames(StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory, ItemReader<String> columnNamesReader, ColumnNamesWriter columnNamesWriter) {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("determineColumnNames").<String, String> chunk(1000).reader(columnNamesReader).writer(columnNamesWriter).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step readAccessDb(StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory, ItemReader<WeeklyStoreItem> importReader, ItemWriter<WeeklyStoreItem> weeklyStoreItemWriter, PlatformTransactionManager legacyTransactionManager) {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("readAccessDb").<WeeklyStoreItem, WeeklyStoreItem> chunk(chunkSize).reader(importReader).writer(weeklyStoreItemWriter).transactionManager(legacyTransactionManager).build();
    }

...
```

At any point in the job execution if any step fails, I want to be able to exit out and do two things:

1. Move the file being processed to specfic folder.
2. Have the scheduler know via the program exit code that an error occurred.

Right now, the job will exit when an uncaught exception occurs, which is partially what I want, but Spring handles the exception, logs it, and then exits gracefully back to my main method.  At that point, I'm not sure how to capture whether the job run was truly successful.

Comment: using a `JobListener.afterJob()`?

Comment: There's also a `SpringApplicationRunListener` and a public static utility method in `SpringApplication.exit()`

Comment: @DaveSyer Ok, so I implemented the `SpringApplicationRunListener` and I'm calling the `SpringApplication.exit(...)` method from the finished hook.  How do I get access to the exit code?  The run method returns a `ConfigurableApplicationContext` in my main method, but I can't figure out how to use it to get at any exit status.

Comment: The access code is the in value returned from `SpringApplication.exit(...)`. I feel like one of us is missing something. I assume you would want to call `System.exit()` with it?

Comment: @DaveSyer So you're saying basically never let it go back to my main method where I called  Spring to begin with.  Interesting.  That would just mean that whatever additional shutdown logic I need to do is moved from my main to the `finished()` method in the listener so that I could exit from there.

Comment: Or else you can just use the finished method to harvest the exception, and then grab it later in the main method. You can do the same with an `ApplicationListener<ApplicationFailedEvent>` (since the default listener publishes one of those events).

Comment: @DaveSyer  The problem I'm having with this is that the `Throwable` passed to the `finished` method is null.  I was able to make this work by adding an `ExceptionHandler` to all of my steps, but I've already found that to be insufficient because I've an encountered an exception with one of my read steps (due to closed datasource) that isn't sent to the `ExceptionHandler` that I defined for the step.

Comment: It's not an exception that gets rethrown by Spring Batch then (nearly all would be in that category I guess, when I think about it). You have to look at the step that fails to get the exception. Why do you need it though?

Comment: In this particular job, any failure needs to abort the job, the file needs to be moved to an error folder, and an error code needs to be returned so the schedule can detect and send notifications to IT staff.

I'm considering solving it for now by adding a tasklet as the last step that essentially sets a success value.  If an exception happens before that and that tasklet doesn't execute, then I'll know that the job failed.  It's very hackish and I don't want to do, but I'm struggling finding a way in the spring documentation to do what I need, and what I feel should be very simple.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I managed to solve partially like this (Dave Sayer outlined this idea already in comment).

First I created this created listener:

```
import org.springframework.batch.core.ExitStatus;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobExecutionEvent;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener;

public class JobResultListener implements
    ApplicationListener<JobExecutionEvent> {
  private ExitStatus jobExitStatus;

  public ExitStatus getJobExitStatus() {
    return jobExitStatus;
  }

  @Override
  public void onApplicationEvent(JobExecutionEvent event) {
    jobExitStatus = event.getJobExecution().getExitStatus();
  }
}
```

Than I used it to get job execution status this way:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application{

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication springApplication =
        new SpringApplication(Application.class);

    JobResultListener jobResultListener = new JobResultListener();
    springApplication.addListeners(jobResultListener);
    springApplication.run(args);

    if (!ExitStatus.COMPLETED.equals(jobResultListener.getJobExitStatus())) {
      throw new IllegalStateException("Job failed");
    }
  }
}
```

But for some reason I wasn't able to get instances of exceptions from injected event. But as you mentioned, error is logged into app logs so this mechanism was enough for me to inform called of my process about error with error code != 0.

BTW, I observed that some error penetrated from `springApplication.run(args)` call, but not sure why not all. Also I didn't find anything mentioned in Spring Boot docs